# Strength of Inter-molecular force: Biscuit Vs Water

Tags: solid-state-physics, interactions, liquid-state

I take two plates and put a few biscuits in one plate and water in another. I drop a heavy pen from a certain height on each plate. I find that biscuit is smashed into several pieces and water momentarily separates out at the point of striking but eventually regains its original shape.

I read in books that intermolecular force is stronger in solids as compared to liquid. But this observation seems contradictory. Or is there a fallacy in my explanation about intermolecular forces in Solid vs Liquid?

Answer (score 0):

But is the biscuit really a solid, or a combination of a solid and lots of air?

It’s just a guess, but perhaps the biscuit breaks is because the biscuit’s structure is highly cellular in nature and its comprised of a great deal of air. If that’s the case you may be comparing the intermolecular forces of air and water, as opposed to a solid and water.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's because  water can easily form and break the hydrogen bonds with its own kind. Hence as soon as the pen moves out of the way, the water flows(because it has weak inter-molecular forces) to fill that region and thus making new hydrogen bonds while a biscuit can't flow because it has stronger forces holding it up hence it can't flow and recombine with other broken parts of the biscuit. Also physically bringing the biscuit together won't help because at the microscopic scale there will always be a big enough gap.

Comment: You have pointed out that the OP’s assumption that the water bonds don’t break is incorrect and that is good but the last statement confuses me. The biscuits actually break apart and don’t simply deform under the weight of the pen. It sounds like you are saying something prevents the broken parts of the biscuit “flowing” back together which of course they would never do.

Comment: @BobD No, I wanted to say that we can't snap the biscuit pieces back together like before by physically bringing them together.

Comment: OK, got it. it just sounded that way to me.